# Cassandra - "The system cannot find the file specified"

Tags: windows, cassandra, windows-10, cassandra-3.0

I have installed Cassandra on Windows 10, and now when I try to run it using "cassandra", I get the following error:

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: What precise version of Cassandra & Java do you have - with subversions...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After looking at the file it seems, powershell script `cassandra-env.ps1` executes following function:

```
if (Test-Path Env:\JAVA_HOME)
{
    $env:JAVA_BIN = "$env:JAVA_HOME\bin\java.exe"
}
elseif (Get-Command "java.exe")
{
    $env:JAVA_BIN = "java.exe"
}
else
{
    echo "ERROR!  No JAVA_HOME set and could not find java.exe in the path."
    exit
}
```

I'm not an expert on Cassandra stuff, but if I were you I would run this script and make sure `$env:JAVA_BIN` is set correctly, and from there I would follow its trail and check 
`ParseJVMInfo` function in the `conf\cassandra-env.ps1` file which is throwing error in your setup.

**Update:**
Check **JAVA_HOME** environment variable and see if it is setup **such that [JAVA_HOME]\bin\java.exe exists**.

Comment: JAVA_HOME is set to C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181 and JAVA_BIN is set to C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\bin\java.exe

Comment: How do I run the script you wrote?

Comment: I did not write any svripts they are already part of Cassandra package. You can run it in powershell window. In the powershell window can you copy script from ParseJVMInfo function and try to run it. (You can find it in [Cassandra]\conf\cassandra-env.ps1 location)

Comment: @Alon wait, if you have path set correctly then how come you are running Cassandra on D:\Program Files? Shouldn't your java file should be in D:\ as well?

Comment: I'm not supposed to install Java on every drive. It's supposed to work on other drives if the env variables are set correctly.

Comment: @Alon That is fine, I just wanted to confirm if you know that they are on different drive. Can you post your cassandra-env.ps1 file located in `D:\Program Files\DataStax-DDC\apache-cassandra\conf` folder?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179555/discussion-between-dipen-shah-and-alon).

Answer (score 3):

Don't install Cassandra into directory where the name has space in it. Startup script for Windows has problems with such names.

Update after an additional investigation:

Looking more precisely into the code, it looks like it can't start Java with the given command-line switches: `-d64 -version` - either Java executable isn't in the PATH, or the `-d64` switch isn't supported for your version of Java - for example, if you installed 32-bit version of Java. Please try to run the `java -d64 -version` from the command line to check that it works

Comment: Good catch!  I'm convinced that Cassandra on Windows is for people who like to torture themselves.  LOL.

Comment: I had somewhere a patch for both `cassandra.sh` & `cassandra.ps1` to fix this, but I can't find it right now, although I thought that I've filed the JIRA for it... I think that Linux version also has problems with files with space in the name, but it's not really common.

Comment: I've reinstalled it at D:\Software\DataStax-DDC\apache-cassandra and it keeps throwing the same error.

Comment: java -d64 -version prints "Unrecognized option: -d64", and so does java -d32 -version

Comment: Ok - this explain it - you need to check how have you installed Java - do you have JRE or JDK? Unfortunately I'm not familiar with Windows

Comment: I've reinstalled Java 8 and now java -d64 -version works fine, but I stil get the same error when I try to run cassandra.

Answer (score 2):

In my case I updated my java version and added latest version in system environment and run this command as administrator in cassandra specieid path(C:\Program Files\apache-cassandra-3.11.6\bin).

```
cassandra.bat -f
```

its running perfactly!!

and also make sure You must allow the execution of PowerShell Scripts. for this check out this one
https://www.howtogeek.com/106273/how-to-allow-the-execution-of-powershell-scripts-on-windows-7/

Answer (score 0):

actually  , its not about the path ... 
its about giving the proper access / privilege to the path you are trying to access , that's something have to do with UAC setting on windows , try minimize it and make sure you have the right access through clicking on folder properties and giving permission to your user or everyone to access this path read / change or full control .

so u don't have to uninstall anything :)